# How to know spring boot app is running via mvn spring-boot:run or java execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My spring boot application can runs mvn spring-boot:run or java execution, I need to know in which mode the application is running inside the main method.

Comment: why do you need that ?

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run` is a wrapper for running java command, `main` method does not even know if it was run with `java -jar`, with IDE or with mvn command.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just detect it, but you can help yourself by setting a property that you can check in your code:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Drunning.from.maven=true"
```

Then you can check using

```
System.getProperty("running.from.maven") 
// or 
Boolean.getBoolean("running.from.maven")
```

Or using Spring. Whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **72.6 Set the active Spring profiles** & **72.7 Change configuration depending on the environment** will be helpfull:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

You can set different profiles for different configurations(e.g. production, dev).